# Inflating layout in android

Tags: android, xml

Hi i want to inflate an xml layout in another layout. Iam doing it correctly but it is not properly coming. Because the page in which i inflating the layout contains 2 relative layouts. I give different id's`android:id="@+id/stocklist"` and `android:id="@+id/gifts"` for the two relative layouts. The stocklist layout contains a + button and when we click the + button it has to inflate the layout below to it.When iam inflating another layout inside the stocklist layout, the inflated xml is not properly alligned and it is not coming below the parent layout. Please help me if anybody knows. I added my code and layout here.

My parent layout code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/ScrollView01"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="704dp"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView9"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/textView8"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/textView8"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textView7"
        android:text="Quantity"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/stocklist"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView8"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView8"
        android:layout_marginTop="11dp"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <Spinner
            android:id="@+id/spinproducts"
            android:layout_width="175dp"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="13dp"
            android:ems="10"
            android:hint="Stocklist Name" >
        </Spinner>

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/editText1"
            android:layout_width="150dp"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:layout_alignTop="@+id/spinproducts"
            android:layout_marginLeft="146dp"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/spinproducts"
            android:ems="10"
            android:inputType="number"
            android:hint="Qty" />

        <CheckBox
            android:id="@+id/checkBox1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/editText1"
            android:layout_marginRight="136dp"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/spindetail" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button1"
            style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
            android:layout_width="40dp"
            android:layout_height="45dp"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_marginRight="11dp"
            android:onClick="onAddNewClicked"
            android:text="+" />

        <Spinner
            android:id="@+id/spindetail"
            android:layout_width="180dp"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_marginRight="50dp"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/button1"
            android:ems="10"
            android:hint="Remarks" />

    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/gifts"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView8"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView12"
        android:layout_marginTop="11dp"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <Spinner
            android:id="@+id/spingift"
            android:layout_width="375dp"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="13dp"
            android:ems="10"
            android:hint="Stocklist Name" >
        </Spinner>

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/etgiftqty"
            android:layout_width="500dp"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/spingift"
            android:layout_marginLeft="33dp"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/spingift"
            android:ems="10"
            android:inputType="number"
            android:hint="Qty" >
        </EditText>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button1"
            style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
            android:layout_width="40dp"
            android:layout_height="45dp"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:text="+" />

    </RelativeLayout>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView13"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView12"
        android:layout_below="@+id/gifts"
        android:layout_marginTop="33dp"
        android:text="Call Outcome :"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView15"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView14"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView14"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:text="Follow Up:"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView12"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/stocklist"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:text="Gifts / Others :"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView8"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView12"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView7"
        android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
        android:text="Product"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText3"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView13"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/editText8"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView13"
        android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
        android:ems="10" >

    </EditText>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/spinner4"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="13dp"
        android:text="Dr.Not Available" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/editText6"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
        android:text="Add Call" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button4"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="51dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/button3"
        android:text="Cancel" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView5"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/spinner1"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/textView9"
        android:text="In Time:"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

    <MultiAutoCompleteTextView
        android:id="@+id/multiAutoCompleteTextView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/spinner3"
        android:layout_marginRight="17dp"
        android:ems="10" >

    </MultiAutoCompleteTextView>

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText8"
        android:layout_width="130dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/editText7"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/editText7"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/multiAutoCompleteTextView1"
        android:ems="10" 
        android:hint="Notes">

    </EditText>

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText6"
        android:layout_width="120dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/spinner3"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/spinner4"
        android:ems="10" 
        android:hint="Amount">

    </EditText>

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText7"
        android:layout_width="120dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/editText6"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/editText6"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/editText8"
        android:ems="10" 
        android:hint="date"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView17"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/textView15"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/editText7"
        android:text="Spon.Req"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView7"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView8"
        android:layout_below="@+id/spinner1"
        android:text="Detailing and Samples Dispensed :"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/spinner1"
        android:layout_width="180dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView7"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView2" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView14"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/editText3"
        android:layout_below="@+id/editText3"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:text="Schedule Follow"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/spinner1"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
        android:text="Location of Visit"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:text="Doctor Name"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:textColor="#008000"
        android:textSize="35dp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText4"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/textView15"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/textView15"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/editText5"
        android:ems="10" >

    </EditText>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView4"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/multiAutoCompleteTextView1"
        android:layout_marginLeft="41dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/button4"
        android:text="Work with"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView10"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/textView9"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/textView9"
        android:layout_marginRight="38dp"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/textView17"
        android:text="Detailed"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />

    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/spinner2"
        android:layout_width="123dp"
        android:layout_height="38dp"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView9"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/textView5"
        android:layout_marginLeft="22dp" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText5"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/editText4"
        android:layout_marginLeft="29dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="11dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/spinner1"
        android:ems="10" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView16"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/editText5"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/editText5"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView15"
        android:text="Follow Up Actions:"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView11"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/stocklist"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/editText7"
        android:layout_marginLeft="25dp"
        android:text="Discussion Topics"       
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView6"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/textView10"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView2"
        android:text="Out Time:"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/spinner3"
        android:layout_width="123dp"
        android:layout_height="38dp"
        android:layout_above="@+id/textView7"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/textView11" />

    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/spinner4"
        android:layout_width="145dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/textView10"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/editText5" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/spinner3"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/spinner4"
        android:text="Duration of Visit"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

 </RelativeLayout>
    </ScrollView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

[image]

Layout which has to be inflated:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <RelativeLayout       
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView8"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView8"
        android:layout_marginTop="11dp"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <Spinner
            android:id="@+id/inflatespinproducts"
            android:layout_width="175dp"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="13dp"
            android:ems="10"
            android:hint="Stocklist Name" >
        </Spinner>

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/inflateeditText1"
            android:layout_width="150dp"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:layout_alignTop="@+id/inflatespinproducts"
            android:layout_marginLeft="146dp"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/inflatespinproducts"
            android:ems="10"
            android:inputType="number"
            android:hint="Qty" />

        <CheckBox
            android:id="@+id/inflatecheckBox1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/inflateeditText1"
            android:layout_marginRight="136dp"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/inflatespindetail" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/inflatebutton1"
            style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
            android:layout_width="40dp"
            android:layout_height="45dp"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_marginRight="11dp"
            android:onClick="onDeleteClicked"
            android:text="-" />

        <Spinner
            android:id="@+id/inflatespindetail"
            android:layout_width="180dp"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_marginRight="50dp"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/inflatebutton1"
            android:ems="10"
            android:hint="Remarks" />

    </RelativeLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

After inflating the layout my page looks like:

[image]

https://i.stack.imgur.com/SOWBJ.png">

My source code:

```
package abts.medismo.e_detailing;

import abts.medismo.e_detailing.Model.Spinmodel;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.CheckBox;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.MultiAutoCompleteTextView;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;
import android.widget.Spinner;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class addcall extends Activity {
    CheckBox chkdetailed;
    TextView txtdocname, txtdisctopic;
    MultiAutoCompleteTextView autoWorkwith;
    Spinner spinlocation, intime, outtime, spinproducts, spingift, spindetail,
            spinSponsorship;
    String docid, docname, addid, addname, straddid, straddname, spaddid,
            spaddname, dbcatid, dbcatname;
    String strcatid, strcatname, spcatid, spcatname;
    String spinlocationvalue, spingiftvalue, spinintimevalue, spinouttimevalue,
            spinproductvalue, spinworkwithvalue, spindetailvalue,
            spinsponsorshipvalue;
    Intent bgIntent;
    EditText etprodqty,etgiftqty;
    RelativeLayout relStocklist;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.dupaddcall);                
        autoWorkwith = (MultiAutoCompleteTextView) findViewById(R.id.multiAutoCompleteTextView1);
        autoWorkwith
                .setTokenizer(new MultiAutoCompleteTextView.CommaTokenizer());
        etprodqty=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText1);
        etgiftqty=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.etgiftqty);
        relStocklist=(RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.stocklist);
        spinlocation = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner1);
        spindetail = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spindetail);
        spinSponsorship = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner4);
        chkdetailed = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.checkBox1);
        chkdetailed.setChecked(true);
        intime = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner2);
        outtime = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner3);
        spinproducts = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinproducts);
        spingift = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spingift);
        txtdocname = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        txtdisctopic = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView11);
        spindetail.setEnabled(false);
        bgIntent = getIntent();
        docid = bgIntent.getStringExtra("docid");
        docname = bgIntent.getStringExtra("docname");
        txtdocname.setText(docname);
        DatabaseHandler dbh = new DatabaseHandler(addcall.this);
        SQLiteDatabase db = dbh.getWritableDatabase();
        addid = null;
        addname = null;


    }

    public void onAddNewClicked(View v) {

        inflateEditRow(null);
        //v.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);        
    }

    private void inflateEditRow(String name) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        final View rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.inflateaddproduct, null);

        // A TextWatcher to control the visibility of the "Add new" button and
        // handle the exclusive empty view.

        // Inflate at the end of all rows but before the "Add new" button
        relStocklist.addView(rowView, relStocklist.getChildCount());
    }

    public void onDeleteClicked(View v) {
        relStocklist.removeView((View) v.getParent());
    }

    public void onBackPressed() {
        super.onBackPressed();
        Intent intent = new Intent(addcall.this, DCR.class);
        intent.putExtra("planid", bgIntent.getStringExtra("planid"));
        intent.putExtra("tourdate", bgIntent.getStringExtra("tourdate"));
        final int result = 1;
        startActivityForResult(intent, result);
        finish();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should change your relative stocklist layout to a linear layout, so the inflated layouts automatically arrange below each other.

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/stocklist"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    ... >
    ...
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: can you plaese design that particular layout in linear? i dont know what iam doing wrong.

Comment: i would start with an empty layout like that and then in your `onCreate()` (or whenever that activity is shown first) inflate your layout the first time. also i would suggest in your inflated layout to remove either the outer linearlayout or the relativelayout, as one of them is useless

Comment: i think linearlayout cannot be used in this scenario. because i want the stocklist layout be vertical. using linearlayout, the stocklist layout can't be created in vertical.

Comment: if u set the orientation to vertical then how can u design the controls in horizontal? see i want the widgets to be in horizontal and the layout in vertical. please see my xml design in the screenshot.

Comment: you can have a vertical linearlayout, so what you inflate into that layout is arranged below each other. and that layout, that you inflate, can be a horizontal linearlayout or a relativelayout if you want, so the view in that layout are arranged side by side. so in the and you have a vertical layout containing multiple inflated horizontal layouts, containing your buttons and spinners and whatelse

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/42401/discussion-between-user1498488-and-grexter89)